# Problem with mounting NFS share in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, nfs

I'm trying to mount an NFS share from an old Netgear ReadyNAS duo NAS on a new Ubuntu 20.04 server

NAS IP address is 192.168.1.102

When I try "sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.102:c/Films /films" I get the error "mount.nfs: mount system call failed"

Despite a long search for answers, I can't solve it - so reaching out to the community for help!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo apt install nfs-common
```

This will give you the packages required for NFS mounts to work.

Comment: kiwichrish - thanks for the quick response, but nfs already installed on the client & upgraded to the latest version.  NFS protocols also enabled on the NAS, with the IP address of the client specified

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have mis-typed the mount command. Immediately following the IP address of the server, there should be a colon and a forward slash. You have the colon but the forward slash is missing. So, your mount command should be:

```
sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.102:/c/Films /films
```

However, the folder name "c" is suspect in my view. You can check this by typing

```
exportfs
```

as root on the server (or go to System - Volumes on the Netgear). On my NAS, exportfs returns

```
 /volume1/Public
        192.168.1.0/24
```

so my mount command is

```
sudo mount -v nas:/volume1/Public /media/$USER/NAS/
```

In my case the IP of the server "nas" resolves as it is in the /etc/hosts file.

If the output of your exportfs command is as follows (or the exported volume name is just "c"):

```
/c/Films
```

then the addition of the forward slash in your client's mount command is all you need.

I have not quoted the "-t nfs" as the mount command is capable of determining the mount type required.

From Netgear, the full information required is here:

```
mount [-t nfs] <ReadyNAS IP address>:/<volume name>/<shared folder name> <mount point>

•<ReadyNAS IP address> is the IP address of the ReadyNAS.

•<volume name> is the name of the volume on which the shared folder resides.

•<shared folder name> is the name of the shared folder that you want to access.

•<mount point> is the name of an empty folder on the Linux or Unix device.
```

Source: https://kb.netgear.com/23181/How-do-I-access-a-shared-folder-on-my-ReadyNAS-OS-6-storage-system-by-using-a-network-attached-Linux-or-Unix-device